# How can I use BigQuery json credentials in a .env file on my django project?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Instead of using the BigQuery authentication JSON file for credentials, I am trying to isolate it on a .env, which is the GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_JSON which I am importing from settings:

```py
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_JSON= 
  "type":"",
  "project_id":"",
  "private_key_id":"",
  "private_key":"",
  "client_email":"",
  "client_id":"",
  "auth_uri":"",
  "token_uri":"",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"",
  "client_x509_cert_url":"",
  "universe_domain":"",
  "client_secret":"",
}
```

```py
def fetching_data_from_loona(self):

    try:

        credentials = GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_JSON
        client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project="loona")
        Loona.objects.all().delete()

        sql = f"""
            SELECT file.project as name, COUNT(*) as downloads
            FROM `bigquery-public-data.loona.file_downloads`
            WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY)
            BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('{(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}') AND TIMESTAMP('{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}')
            GROUP BY name
            ORDER BY downloads DESC
            LIMIT 5000
        """

        query_job = client.query(sql)
        rows = query_job.result()

        for row in rows:
            name = Loona(name=row['name'], downloads=row['singles'])
            name.save()

    except RequestException as e:
        try:
            raise self.retry(exc=e, countdown=60)
        except MaxRetriesExceededError:
            print(f"Failed to sync loona after {self.max_retries} attempts")
```

`your text`

However, I get this issue when I try to fetch, different of when I fetch with JSON file. I wish I could use the json file, but for security reasons, I have to use another way like virtual envs, but I am getting this issue like google does not accept my credentials if they are not from the json file.

```bash
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 fetching_data_from_loona()

File /app/tasks.py:155, in fetching_data_from_loona(self)
    152 try:
    154     credentials = GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_JSON
--> 155     client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project="loona")
    156     Loona.objects.all().delete()
    158     sql = f"""
    159         SELECT file.project as name, COUNT(*) as downloads
    160         FROM `bigquery-public-data.loona.file_downloads`
   (...)
    165         LIMIT 50
    166     """

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py:245, in Client.__init__(self, project, credentials, _http, location, default_query_job_config, default_load_job_config, client_info, client_options)
    234 def __init__(
    235     self,
    236     project=None,
   (...)
    243     client_options=None,
    244 ) -> None:
--> 245     super(Client, self).__init__(
    246         project=project,
    247         credentials=credentials,
    248         client_options=client_options,
    249         _http=_http,
    250     )
    252     kw_args = {"client_info": client_info}
    253     bq_host = _get_bigquery_host()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py:321, in ClientWithProject.__init__(self, project, credentials, client_options, _http)
    319 def __init__(self, project=None, credentials=None, client_options=None, _http=None):
    320     _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
--> 321     Client.__init__(
    322         self, credentials=credentials, client_options=client_options, _http=_http
    323     )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py:167, in Client.__init__(self, credentials, _http, client_options)
    160     raise google.api_core.exceptions.DuplicateCredentialArgs(
    161         "'credentials' and 'client_options.credentials_file' are mutually exclusive."
    162     )
    164 if credentials and not isinstance(
    165     credentials, google.auth.credentials.Credentials
    166 ):
--> 167     raise ValueError(_GOOGLE_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_HELP)
    169 scopes = client_options.scopes or self.SCOPE
    171 # if no http is provided, credentials must exist

ValueError: This library only supports credentials from google-auth-library-python. See https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for help on authentication with this library.
```

Comment: Where are you running your code? Service account key file (JSON) has to be use in very rare and specific cases. In all other, you have alternative without this dangerous file.